# Cadence Workflow Server Upgrade (0.12.1 to 0.16.0): Is running the unsupported workflow command always required?

Tags: cadence-workflow

I'm attempting to upgrade Cadence from 12.1 to 16.0 and beyond. None of my workflows will be open for longer than a month, but they all have been started on v12.1. Do I still need to run unsupported workflows command as described here:

> MySQL/Postgres:
>
> cadence admin db unsupported-workflow --db_type=<mysql/postgres>
> --db_address  --db_port  --username= --password= --db_name  --lower_shard_bound= --upper_shard_bound= --rps  --output_filename ./cadence_scan

If so, is my shard ID range simply 1-`numHistoryShards`? What are reasonable values for `rps` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should still do it unless the workflow are already deleted by system due to retention config.

The reason is that there will be still some active internal  tasks  for those closed workflow, for example delete the workflow or visibility, or background scan etc. another reason is that Cadence allows users to use  reset to reopen a closed workflow to any point of the history.

For RPS, it depends on your database current workload. I would try at least 10, and try a larger number if you think the database can take it on top of the current load.

Comment: Understood. If my `numHistoryShards` is `4`, are my shard ids 0,1,2,3 ? If not, is there a way to list my shards id?

Thanks for the clarification and all the work!

Comment: Yes that’s correct. To list all the shards, you can use the CLI command to describe the cluster: cadence admin cluster desc